# How do I reverse criss cross pattern without having to redraw the whole path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'm building a vector logo with one long continuous path and I realized there is an area where the vector path is crossed leaving a very tiny gap in the design. The only way I know how to fix this is to redraw the entire area and flip vertices by vertices.

[image]

Comment: No clue how anyone could guess and what you are referring to without actually seeing an image or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a white stroke at a joint?
You might repair it by changing the stroke cap and/or corner to round:

[image]

If the path has been expanded, are there nodes at these points?:

[image]

If so just delete the middle 1 or 2 and repair sides with the pen tool,
or draw a shape like this and combine it with your path with Pathfinder>Unite:

[image]

Comment: THIS WORKED!!! Thank you so so much!! I will never forget this trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can add new path anchor points. You may need 6 new points - 2 for separating the halves and 4 as guards who limit the surgery area.

Then, by the direct selection tool delete a couple of anchors. That kills also the pieces of the path around them. You do not lose very much if the guard points are not far away.

Now you have separated halves that can be edited in all ways separately. Do the edits, then draw what's missing between the parts. Start by the Pen and in the beginning and the end drag the handles into the right direction.

If you got an unwanted corner, double click on it by the "Covert Anchor Point" -tool.

Practice at first. Draw a 8 and edit it to a zero or other non-crossing loop.